# How to call label in controller in C# .net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a question (maybe simple.. ) I'm a beginner in C# .net on Visual Studio.

I explain to you my problem : After I do something, it put me a number into a label (or anything I want) and I want to redirect in different views depending on what is in the label.

I tried to simply make a

```
if (label = 1) { return view1 } else...
```

etc

But I can't find how to call my view label in my controller :(

Comment: What is the html you have in your view, which has the textbox for number input?

Comment: My view is totally basic, I explain, I call the camera, I scan a barcode, read it and it put me the barcode into a label (or comething else if you want) I just don't know how to say in my controller "get this label text"

Comment: Ok. Then I suggest use a control which has its value also posted back, so you can get the value in your controller. For example, use a textbox or hidden field.

Comment: Okay I will search how to do that, thx for the track ^^

Comment: I have provided you an answer with all details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a textbox or a hidden field for storing the barcode scanned value. Make sure you give a name attribute for the control. Then, in your controller simply use code below to get the barcode value scanned. You must use a control whose value is posted back else you cannot get the value in your controller.

```
Request.Form["txtScannedValue"]
```

I would prefer to use a hidden field for capturing the scanned value rather than a textbox.

Your html should have one of the following element to capture the scanned value. If using a textbox, you could set its display property to none in your CSS.

```
<input id="txtScannedValue" name="txtScannedValue" type="text" />
<input id="hdnScannedValue" name="hdnScannedValue" type="hidden" />
```

Controller code in C#

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostbackAction()
    {
        // Add action logic here
       string scannedValue =  Request.Form["txtScannedValue"].ToString();
       //string scannedValue =  form["hdnScannedValue"];
       if( scannedValue == "1" ) {
          return View("View1");
        } else if (scannedValue== "2") {
          return View("View2");
       }
    }
}
```

You could also use `FormCollection` object that is automatically passed if you use the C# code below.

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Products/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostbackAction(FormCollection form)
    {
       // Add action logic here
       string scannedValue =  form["txtScannedValue"];
       //string scannedValue =  form["hdnScannedValue"];
       if( scannedValue == "1" ) {
          return View("View1");
        } else if (scannedValue== "2") {
          return View("View2");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh I begin to see how it work, thx for the method ! I will try !

Comment: Sure. It's very easy if you understand the basics. The basics in MVC are the same as that of any other web technology you have been exposed to.

Comment: Thx ! I make it a bit different but your answer clearly help me to think and to understand ! I just pass my barcode in the URL as a parameters "id" and use it in my controller :D Thx a lot !

Comment: You are welcome. Yes passing parameters is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

Html works as you expect as it says, simply MODEL-VIEW-CONTROLLER.

You create your model, pass data to the view, then pass data to the controller from your view.

**In order to resolve your conflict there are two ways:**

**1)** create a method that accepts the value and pass the value from the view:

in your controller: `public ActionResult(string labelValue)`

in your view:  `@Html.Label("labelValue", "MyLabel", new {Value = labelValue})`

**2)** Add property to your model and pass it your label value, then pass the model to your controller:

In your model : `public string labelValue { get; set;}`

in your controller: `public ActionResult(MyModel model)`

in your view:  `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.labelValue, "MyLabel", new {Value = labelValue})`